# Compilation error when starting the cucumber project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gherkin, cucumber-java

When trying to run test script (feature file) one of two errors occur. Name and content of feature file are non-ASCII characters. Using Windows 10.

Error before changing "Language for non-Unicode programs" setting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 3
^???????? ??????????? ? ??? ????????$
```

Error after changing setting:

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to parse resource at: file:/C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/proj/src/test/resources/features/???????????.feature
    at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:25)
    at ru.sbtqa.tag.pagefactory.utils.GherkinSerializer.lambda$0(GherkinSerializer.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at ru.sbtqa.tag.pagefactory.utils.GherkinSerializer.reserializeFeatures(GherkinSerializer.java:41)
    at ru.sbtqa.tag.pagefactory.aspects.FragmentsAspect.replaceSteps(FragmentsAspect.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:30)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:67)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:26)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: gherkin.ParserException$CompositeParserException: Parser errors:
(3:1): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '??????????: ???????????'
(5:3): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '???????????:'
(6:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '????  ???????????? ????????? ?? ???????? "???????"'
(7:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '*  ?? (????????? ????)'
(10:3): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '????????: ???????? ??????????? ? ??? ????????'
(11:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '?  ?? (???????? ????? ???????? ????) " ??????????? "'
(12:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '?????  ?? ????????? ?? ???????? "???????????"'
(13:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '*  ?? (??????? ???????? ??????)'
(14:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '*  ?? ??????? ?? ?????? "????? ??????????"'
(15:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '*  (???? ????????? ? ???????) "???????? ???????????"'
(16:5): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got '*  ?? ?????????? ????????? ?????? ? ?????? "10" ? ????????? ? ?????????? "??????????"'
    at gherkin.Parser.addError(Parser.java:152)
    at gherkin.Parser.matchTokenAt_2(Parser.java:569)
    at gherkin.Parser.matchToken(Parser.java:343)
    at gherkin.Parser.parse(Parser.java:137)
    at gherkin.Parser.parse(Parser.java:118)
    at gherkin.Parser.parse(Parser.java:114)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:36)
    ... 9 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also tried to change encoding settings in IDE - same result.

Comment: What are the full stack traces for both exceptions?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje
Edited the post. The first exception was no longer reproduced.

Comment: At a glance you need to change the encoding of the file to be UTF-8. Not just in your IDE, but when the file is saved. Also, you should probably upgrade Cucumber.